# My iPhone app is crashing and showing [__NSCFDictionary stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, string

My iPhone application is crashing and showing error :

`- [__NSCFDictionary stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x99f60b0`

Here is my code
     NSString *strData;
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (delegate.respondInsightIndex)
    {
        strData = [insights objectAtIndex:index];
    }
    else
    {
        strData = [insights lastObject];
    }

```
NSString *strReplace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[strData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "]];
```

this is my method where the crash is happening again

```
- (void) setComments:(NSArray*)comments {
NSString * htmlString; 
if ( [UIHelper isPad] )
    htmlString = @"<html><style type=\"text/css\">body{padding:15px 40px 0 40px; font-family: Helvetica;"
                "font-size: 14px;"
                "color: #888888;"
                "line-height: 50%"
                "},</style><body>";
else
    htmlString = @"<html><style type=\"text/css\">body{padding:8px 20px 0 20px; font-family: Helvetica;"
                "font-size: 11px;"
                "color: #888888;"
                "},</style><body>";

for ( NSString * single in comments ) {
    if ( single == nil ) 
        single = @"";

    if ([single isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        single = [single stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "];  
    }
    NSString * str ;
    if([UIHelper isPad ])
    {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<br/><hr color=#555555><p align=\"right\" style=\"font-size:12px;\">Username</p>", single];
    }
    else {
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<br/><hr color=#555555><p align=\"right\" style=\"font-size:9px;\">Username</p>", single];
    }

    htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", htmlString, str];
}
htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", htmlString, @"</body></html>"];
if ( [contentView respondsToSelector:@selector(loadHTMLString:baseURL:)] )
    [contentView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.secondprizm.com"]];
```

}

Answer (score 5):

So that means that you are trying to use the method `- stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` on an instance of `NSDictionary` which of course will not work.

The object `strData` is not an `NSString` object as you think it is. It is actually an object of `NSDictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

As Peter says above, when you retrieve an object from an `NSArray` it is just a pointer to an object, regardless of what you cast it to. You could investigate this in various ways. look at where the array contents is being set and check what you are adding, it might be possible an `NSDictionary` has been mis-cast further up the chain. Also try setting a breakpoint before the array is read, and type into the debugger `po insights`. This will print the contents of the object. After the crash, you can also investigate the object that has caused the problem by doing a `po <memory address>`, in this case `po 0x99f60b0`.

A good way to safeguard against this kind of thing is with introspection (although this wont solve the problem if you've got the wrong object in your array, but will stop the crash.) as so:

```
if ([strData isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSString *strReplace = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[strData stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "]];   
}
```

I can't see any errors in the code you posted up, although a couple of things I noticed. You don't need to check if `single == nil`. It is not possible to have `nil` in an `NSArray`.

Also you are doing quite a lot of reassignment of pointers, and also trying to edit the contents of the array while looping through the array. This is not such a good idea in Objective-C. I've tested it and it seems to work in this case, but it's generally a good idea to create a new string pointer if you're creating a new string, to ensure the memory used by the old string is released correctly. Don't get me wrong the code works, but this kind of thing can pretty quickly lead to memory leaks that are difficult to track down later, just best practice stuff.

In regards to the crash, I can't see that error message getting generated from that method, and where does the original code you posted fit into the extra code you posted? Please update your question with more details

Comment: Please check my code I have updated it and let me know what is going wrong

Comment: when you breakpoint it and step through it, which line exactly causes the crash? is it `single = [single stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "]; `?

Comment: Hmm I can't find anything wrong with that code, I've tested it my self and it seems ok, try cleaning the project (shift + cmd + k), deleting the the app of the test device / simulator and reinstalling?